# Populate a dropdown list dynamically on the same page using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to populate a drop down from values in DB on the same page which is from input on the same page itself.

I have tried a few options on the forum but it did not help.

After hitting submit it goes to a next page which is blank.

I have tried onchange=AjaxFunction(); as suggested in one post, but i still get a blank page.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my form.php

```
<form action="connection.php" class="form-solid-blue" method="get">
   <div class="title">
      <h2></h2>
      <h2>Tracking & Receiving</h2></div>
      <div class="element-input<?php frmd_add_class("input2"); ?>">
         <label class="title"></label>
         <div class="item-cont">
            <input class="small" type="text" name="store" placeholder="Store #"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element-input<?php frmd_add_class("input"); ?>">
         <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <input class="medium" type="text" name="userid" placeholder="UserId"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      <div class="element-input<?php frmd_add_class("input1"); ?>">
         <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <input class="large" type="text" name="order" placeholder="Order Number"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
         </div>
         <div class="element-separator">
            <hr>
            <h3 class="section-break-title">Tracking Numbers</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="element-multiple<?php frmd_add_class("multiple"); ?>">
            <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <div class="large">
                  <select data-no-selected="Nothing selected" name="multiple[]" multiple="multiple">

                     <option value="option_1">option 1</option>
                     <option value="option_2">option 2</option>
                     <option value="option_3">option 3</option>
                 </select>
              <span class="icon-place"></span>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </div>
 </form>
```

This is the connection.php - Server side code

```
<?php
        // Create connection to Oracle
    $conn = oci_connect("XXXX", "xyxyx", "xyxyx");
    if (!$conn) {
        $m = oci_error();
        echo $m['message'], "\n";
        exit;
    }

    $query = "SELECT TRACKING_NUMBER FROM JC_SHIPPED_ORDER_TRACKING WHERE EXT_PURCHASE_ORDERS_ID = :order_bv";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $order = $_GET['order'];

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':order_bv', $order);
    oci_execute($stid);

   //Because order is a unique value I only expect one row
   $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);
    if (!$row) {
    exit("The order " . $order . " is invalid. Please check and try again" );
   }
   $trackID = $row['TRACKING_NUMBER'];
   echo "<form name=form1 method=POST action='form.php'>";
    //echo "<select name='TRACKING_NUMBER' onchange=AjaxFunction();>";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
    echo "<option value=\"option_1\">" . $row['TRACKING_NUMBER'] . "</option>";


}   
   echo "</select>";
   //echo ("The order " . $order . " is valid.");
   oci_free_statement($stid); 
   oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: why do you try to create another form in side php file if you want to work in the same form.

Comment: @PHJCJO  - Thank you for your response. I'm trying to keep the DB connection and queries separate.And I'm trying to populate the dropdown in the form.php Both the input and the result to the dropdown are in form.php

Comment: yes i understand it, but i see this line echo "<form name=form1 method=POST action='form.php'>"; in your connection.php, why

Comment: @PHJCJO - Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But is this an incorrect way of doing it, or is the syntax incorrect or if something else needs to be added.

Comment: yes you can include the connection.php file in the form.php and populate the list, or you can create the class and call to the method that can draw the list on the form.php. but remember you still have to include the class in the form.php. it is not good the good practice to include the connection.php directly in the page though. for you testing it is ok

Comment: @PHJCJO  - I get the point. But is it possible to do it with the current approach. As you mentioned, I'm also a bit vary about adding the connection details in the form.php itself. If i go with the current approach, what do I need to change/add for it to work?

Comment: submitting the form will always reload the page or go to the url listed in `action` unless you use Ajax.  Using Ajax is too broad a topic here, you would do well to search some tutorials on JSON or Ajax, first.  With Ajax you can send a separate request to the sever ( outside the form submission ) and then have the server return the `select` you need, and replace the old one with JavaScript.

Comment: Also it's unlikely `connection.php` is ever called unless you include it in `form.php`, submitting the form will take you to whatever your url in the browser is as you have no action attribute set in the form tag.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - That is correct. I'm calling the connection.php in action. `<form action="connection.php" class="form-solid-blue" method="get">`. does that change anything

Comment: well, all you will get is what is in that file after the page reloads, not anything from form.php.  ie, load form.php > submit to connection.php > load connection.php.  Everything from form is gone at that point.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - Got the sequence. I will keep the action blank then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can do with the information provided.

in form.php

```
<select data-no-selected="Nothing selected" name="multiple[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php require 'path to connection.php'; ?>
 </select>
```

oh and remove these from connection.php

```
echo "<form name=form1 method=POST action='form.php'>";

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I kept the action blank so that it remains on the same page `<form action="" class="form-solid-blue" method="get">` and added the above code. But this time it did not load the form.php at all